# Add specific shape and linetype to ellipses for NMDS via ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

As a follow up to this extremely useful question and answer:

[Color-coding 95% confidence ellipses for centroids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998853/color-coding-95-confidence-ellipses-for-centroids)

I have manage to successfully overlay confidence ellipses for my NMDS plots in ggplot.  I want now to specify the colour and shape of the data points on the plot, and the colour and linetype of the ellipses, to distinguish between my four treatments.

NMDS is here:

http://pastebin.com/99WcC6wN

Dat2 is here:

http://pastebin.com/D93wrShT

The code I have tried is as follows:

```
ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2)) + geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_path(data=Dat2, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2,colour=group), size=1,     linetype=2)+theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=rel(1.1),vjust=0.2),axis.title.x=element_t    ext(size=rel(1.1),vjust=0.2),axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1)),axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1)),text = element_text(size=13)) +scale_shape_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("W+N-", "W+NC", "WCN-", "WCNC"),
                  values = c("17", "19","17", "19")) +scale_colour_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("W+N-", "W+NC", "WCN-", "WCNC"),
                  values = c("blue", "blue","red", "red")) +scale_linetype_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("W+N-", "W+NC", "WCN-", "WCNC"),
                  values = c("3", "1","3", "1"))
```

Unfortunately, only the colour of the points and ellipses seems to work - the linetype of the ellipses and the shape of the datapoints doesn't seem to change.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to get around this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map `linetype` and `shape` to `group`, just as you mapped `color` to `group`. You can actually do both of these mappings once in the first line, since the name of the variable is the same across your two datasets:

```
ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2, color=group, linetype=group, shape=group))
```

Of course, then you need to delete the `color` and `linetype` mappings elsewhere. You also should specify the `linetype` values in `scale_linetype_manual` as numbers, not strings. In the end, you'll have something like this:

```
ggplot(data = NMDS, aes(MDS1, MDS2, color=group, linetype=group, shape=group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(data=Dat2, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2), size=1) + 
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=rel(1.1),vjust=0.2),axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1.1),vjust=0.2),axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1)),axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1)),text = element_text(size=13)) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("W+N-", "W+NC", "WCN-", "WCNC"), values = c(17, 19,17, 19)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("W+N-", "W+NC", "WCN-", "WCNC"), values = c("blue", "blue","red", "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Treatment", labels = c("W+N-", "W+NC", "WCN-", "WCNC"), values = c(3, 1,3, 1))
```

[image: the desired plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to change the point shapes also, as I had tried to specify?  For these I want W+N- and WCN- to have triangles, and W+NC and WCNC to have normal round points...

Comment: Yes, just map `shape` to the variable of interest. I edited my post to show you.

Comment: Thank you!  Just realised how to do it now :)